# Can you build with a worker and a legion at the same time?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings, civilization-5-brave-new-world

Legions can build roads, which is quite handy. Can you use a worker to improve a tile while a legion is constructing a road at the same tile?

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately. You have to wait until the legion or worker is done.

Protip:

If you want to build a road fast, the combination of a worker and a legion can be very useful. Since they can stand on the same tile, you don't have to waste precious turns while moving around the other unit. This is especially valuable in rough terrain.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. While I haven't tested it lately, I believe you can have both a worker and legion build on the same turn if you cancel the build action on the unit that you have build first.

Comment: @WillemRenzema Could be, but in that case it's a bug. It actually reminds me of Civ I. You could build any tile improvement in one turn by clicking build and then cancel, and then repeat until done.